# merged to datatable with different numbers of entries

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have 2 datable , one like :

```
Date         %change_1
 6/20/2011    0.112
 6/21/2011    0.2365
 6/22/2011    -0.248
6/23/2011    -0.965
6/24/2011    0.123
6/27/2011    0.6544
6/28/2011    -0.789
```

An other one like :

```
Date         %change_2
6/20/2011    -0.45
6/22/2011    -0.6
6/23/2011    0.98
6/27/2011    -0.845
```

I want to merged this to data in order to have only one column for the date like :

```
Date         %change_1   %change_2
6/20/2011    0.112       -0.45
6/22/2011    -0.248      -0.6
6/23/2011    -0.965       0.98
6/27/2011    -0.6544     -0.845
```

I don't want to have any shift in my data (which I have if I simply merged them)

Here is my code

```
        //cherche les last price
        DataTable TickerPrice = new DataTable("Data");
        TickerPrice = CheckBloomi(TickerName + " equity", "CHG_PCT_1D", FromThisTime, ToThisTime);

        //cherche les price indexprice
        DataTable IndexPrice = new DataTable("Data");
        IndexPrice = CheckBloomi(Bchmrk, "CHG_PCT_1D", FromThisTime, ToThisTime);

        DataSet MarketData = new DataSet();
        MarketData.Merge(TickerPrice);
        MarketData.Merge(IndexPrice);

        DataTable Recap = MarketData.Tables.Add("Recap");
```

Thanks

Comment: and where is your code which is not able to do this ?

Comment: What does "don't want to have any shift in my data" mean?

Comment: This means thats i dont want to have the data juste merged and for example I would have the line : 6/22/2011    0.2365      -0.6 according to my example

Answer (score 0):

You need something like SEMIJOIN in relational algebra, in SQL it would look something like this :

```
Select * from Datatable1 D1 
where exists 
( 
    Select * from Datatable D2 where D1.Date = D2.Date 
)
```

Also, you should provide your code which doesn't work

Comment: this sql will select fields from D1 where date is same in D2. Simple join on date should do the trick `select date, change_1, change_2 from table1 join table2 on table1.date = table2.date`